# Прочитать POJO объект из ActiveMQ на джаве, автоматически конвертируя

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq

Я не могу разобраться, как прочитать объект из `ActiveMQ`, который записан в очередь.

Я сконфигурировал JMS так:

```
package aoizora.config;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;

import javax.jms.Queue;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    private final String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    private final String BROKER_USERNAME = "admin";
    private final String BROKER_PASSWORD = "admin";

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        var connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        var template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setDefaultDestinationName("sample.queue");
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("sample.queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        var converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        return converter;
    }
}
```

В очередь кладу простой датакласс, который реализует Serializable:

```
package aoizora.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClaimNotification implements Serializable {

    private String template;
    private ClaimData data;

    public String getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public ClaimData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ClaimData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClaimNotification{" +
                "template='" + template + '\'' +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }

    public String toJson() {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            System.out.println(ignore);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

package aoizora.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClaimData implements Serializable {

    private String claimUid;

    public String getClaimUid() {
        return claimUid;
    }

    public void setClaimUid(String claimUid) {
        this.claimUid = claimUid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClaimData{" +
                "claimUid='" + claimUid + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

За отправку сообщения отвечает класс Producer:

```
package aoizora.activemq;

import aoizora.entity.ClaimNotification;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.jms.Queue;

@Component
public class Producer {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Queue queue;

    public void send(final ClaimNotification notification) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(notification);
        System.out.println("Message sent to the Queue");
    }
}
```

Получает сообщение класс Consumer:

```
package aoizora.activemq;

import aoizora.entity.ClaimNotification;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.jms.TextMessage;

@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "sample.queue")
    public void receive(@Payload ClaimNotification text) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + text);
    }
}
```

В очередь сообщение отправляется без ошибок, но при считывании консюмером возникает ошибка:

> org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void aoizora.activemq.Consumer.receive(aoizora.entity.ClaimNotification)' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not convert JMS message; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class aoizora.entity.ClaimNotification! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.

Как прочитать сообщение из очереди, автоматически конвертируя его в объект?

Comment: по ссылке из исключения можно почерпнуть что необходимо добавить пакет в разрешенные...

Comment: `-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*`

Comment: connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);